# Does a Pending Intent have a lifetime?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, foreground-service

I have an application which in turn runs a foreground service. The application has a start/stop button as part of its notification which as can be guessed starts and stops the foreground service. Upon clicking on the start button a Pending Intent gets triggered.

Consider the following scenario:

The application has been destroyed [removed from the recent items list] but the notification is still visible.
I am able to start and stop the foreground service even when the app has been destroyed, as on clicking the notification button triggers a Pending intent (which in turn call a broadcast receiver).
But, what I have observed is that after a day or two, upon clicking the buttons on the notification the pending intent is not  triggered (that is the foreground service does not start). This begs the question, does pending intent have a lifetime after the encompassing application has been destroyed? Or am I missing something else here?

My pending intent call:

```
Intent notificationBroadcastIntent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent playIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MY_REQUEST_CODE,
                notificationBroadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The Broadcast Receiver called by the pending intent (which in turn starts the foreground service):

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(MyBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "MyBroadcastReceiver called to update service notification");
        
 if (isMyForegroundServiceRunning(MyForegroundService.class, context)) {
            Intent stopIntent = new Intent(context, MyForegroundService.class);
            stopIntent.setAction(STOP_SERVICE_ACTION);
            context.startService(stopIntent);
        } else {
            Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, MyForegroundService.class);
            startIntent.setAction(START_SERVICE_ACTION);
            context.startService(startIntent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PendingIntent`s do not expire. However, they are not persistent and will not survive a reboot of the device.

To see if the `PendingIntent` still exists, you can use the following adb command:

`adb shell dumpsys activity intents`

This lists all of the `PendingIntent`s in the system. You can also look at the notifications using:

`adb shell dumpsys notification`

This will show all `Notification`s, including the `PendingIntent`s that are set for them.

Comment: Appreciate your response. I did want to understand one more thing. If the application has been destroyed  and only the foreground service notification remains, the notification having a button to start and stop the service (pending intent to trigger the start of the service), is there a limit to how long the notification can trigger the pending intent?

Comment: No. There is no time limit. Your problem is something else. On what devices have you seen this behaviour?

Comment: I have observed this on a Samsung phone. If the app has already been destroyed and the button on notification is in stop state (ie., the foreground service is not running) and I don't change the state on the notification for lets say a day, then try to start foreground service from notification (which is a pending intent), I see the foreground service not starting. I have tried debugging from adb but have found no exceptions.

Comment: Hard to believe. Did you check the logcat without filtering it? Sometimes filtering the logcat causes you to miss something important. Have you tried this on other devices?

Comment: After considering all the logs around the time the issue occurred I found this.

**BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.net.conn.DATA_ACTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.oneplus.security/.network.trafficalarm.TrafficUsageAlarmReceiver**. This is an exception that is seen when the call to a foreground service does not use **startForegroundService()**. I have made the necessary change wherever the said call was missed. Will update you if this fixes the issue.

Comment: There are a lot of restrictions now about what background and non-running components can do. It can be very tricky to get everything to work properly.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, I have made the necessary changes (startForegroundService) and over the past 3 days I have not observed any crashes yet. Will monitor this for over a week and I shall update my findings here.

Comment: If this answer was useful, you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. This will remove the question from the list of open questions and might help others with a similar problem.

Comment: Will do. Thank you.

Comment: I made the above mentioned changes (broadcast receiver) and I have not observed the aforementioned issue again. Until further notice, this issue is assumed  to  be fixed.